# SwiftUI - Loop through and list items in nested array in Text element

Tags: arrays, foreach, swiftui

I'm using Swift to call Yelp's API to return local business information. In the JSON response, there are multiple nested arrays, i.e. "Category" that describes what type of business it is. I'm able to return the first item in the array, but I'm lost on how to use ForEach to return each individual item in the array.

The response looks like this:

```
{
    "businesses": [
           "id": XP5BuE79...,
           "categories" : [
                {
                  "alias": "golfcourse",
                  "title": "Golf Course"
                },
                {
                  "alias": "clubhouse",
                  "title": "Clubhouse"
                }
             ],
           ....
}
```

My data model

```
struct BusinessesResponse: Codable {
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case restaurants = "businesses"
}

let restaurants: [RestaurantResponse]
}

struct RestaurantResponse: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    var name: String
    var image_url: String
    var is_closed: Bool
    var review_count: Int
    var rating: Double
    var distance: Double
    var price: String?
    var display_phone: String
    var categories: [RestaurantCategory]
}
```

Currently, I'm able to return the first item in the "categories" array by using

```
VStack {
            ForEach(fetcher.businesses) { restaurant in
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: restaurant.image_url))
                        .resizable()
                        .indicator(.activity) // Activity Indicator
                            .transition(.fade(duration: 0.5)) // Fade Transition with duration
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: 400, height: 200, alignment: .center)
                        .clipped()
                        
                        
                    Text(restaurant.name)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    HStack(spacing: 5.0) {
                        Text(restaurant.price ?? "No Pricing Info")
                            .font(.caption)
                        Text("·")
                        //Category displaying only first in nested array
                        Text(restaurant.categories[0].title)
                            .font(.caption)
                        Text("·")
                        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                            .font(.caption)
                        Text("\(restaurant.rating, specifier: "%.1f")")
                            .font(.caption)
                        Text("(\(restaurant.review_count))")
                            .font(.caption)
                        Spacer()
                    }
            }
            }.padding(.bottom)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? A loop over all the businesses, and then again - over the categories of each business? In a nutshell, you can use a `ForEach` or a `List` depending on what suits you

Comment: Well, I have a ForEach running on all the businesses currently. What I'm looking to do is list all of the categories for each business listing. Currently, I'm only showing the first even if there may be 3 category descriptions.

Comment: You can do another (nested) `ForEach(restaurant.categories, id: \.self) { cat in ...}`

Comment: Thank you, that worked along with adding "Hashable" to my model definition